# Will a member be created with typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I am a novice in C++ programming. So this question may sound silly to you.

```
class ABCD : public VectorS<UINT8, 50>
{
private:
    typedef VectorS<UINT8, 50> XYZ;
    float m_length; 
    float m_angle;

    inline void append_check (const Point2D& pt)
    {
        if (!full())
        {
            push_back (pt);
        }
    }

public:
    typedef Point2Df Point;

    ABCD() : m_length(0), m_angle(0) {}

    void copy (const ABCD& def)
    {
        XYZ::operator=(def);
        m_length = def.getLength();
        m_angle = def.getAngleBound();
    }

    void clear (void)
    {
        XYZ::clear();
    }

}
```

Here what happens with the typedef of XYZ? Will a vector be created with this typedef? I cannot see any member variables created of type XYZ. What happens with XYZ::clear()? What is getting cleared here?

Answer (score 1):

This code is using `typedef` to create a shorter name for its parent class, `VectorS<UINT8, 50>`.

```
void clear (void)
{
    XYZ::clear();
}
```

is the same as

```
void clear (void)
{
    VectorS<UINT8, 50>::clear();
}
```

is the same as

```
void clear (void)
{
    this->VectorS<UINT8, 50>::clear();
}
```

I.e. it's calling the `clear` method inherited from its parent class.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
typedef VectorS<UINT8, 50> XYZ;
```

`XYZ` is declared as an alias for type `VectorS<UINT8, 50>.`

Neither `Vector` is created.

The name itself is a member of the class.

By the way this alias is used in the method

```
void copy (const ABCD& def)
{
    XYZ::operator=(def);
    ^^^^
    m_length = def.getLength();
    m_angle = def.getAngleBound();
}
```

It is the same as

```
void copy (const ABCD& def)
{
    VectorS<UINT8, 50>::operator=(def);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    m_length = def.getLength();
    m_angle = def.getAngleBound();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After `typedef VectorS<UINT8, 50> XYZ;` whenever you write XYZ it would be interpreted as `VectorS<UINT8, 50>`.

`XYZ::clear();` will be interpreted as `VectorS<UINT8, 50>::clear();`.

Comment: Thank you very much